# use php to search a directory for a specifically named image in many subdirectories

Tags: php

I have a directory named property-images

In this directory I have hundreds of subdirectories all named like this 142, 1309, 85, 420, etc. they are not sequential and seem fairly random

In each of these sub directories are a variable amount of images all named with a random filename.jpg, however one of these images from each directory has a filename that starts with MainPSW- and ends with .jpg

I would like to display each image where the filename matches MainPSW-whateverrandomname.jpg only from 10 of the folders.

I am using a database that already gets the 10 results I want and the subfolder name matches the id of the sql results

I have a repeat region that already gives me all the resulting id numbers

```
$getSubFolderName = '{{prop_id}}';
echo $getSubFolderName;
//Returns the 10 folder names
3601
3599
3600
3597
3598
3595
3596
3593
3591
3589

$getEntireDirectory = 'property-images/'.$getSubFolderName.'/';
echo $getEntireDirectory;
//Returns the 10 paths of
property-images/3601/
property-images/3599/
property-images/3600/
property-images/3597/
property-images/3598/
property-images/3595/
property-images/3596/
property-images/3593/
property-images/3591/
property-images/3589/

$imageFinder = glob($getEntireDirectory."MainPSW-*.jpg");
print_r(array_values($imageFinder));
//Returns Array ()
```

If I make an alteration give the full path name instead it works correctly like this

```
$getEntireDirectory = 'property-images/3601/';
$imageFinder = glob($getEntireDirectory."MainPSW-*.jpg");
print_r(array_values($imageFinder));
//Returns Array ( [0] => property-images/3601/MainPSW-4847097c5c2c793ea2acfd86d691ab14.jpg )
```

I have tried everything I know how to do but can not seem to get this working correctly, please could somebody assist. I have also tried DirectoryIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator with not much luck either?

Here is the actual pages code (Please be aware I am using dmxZone Extensions for databindings etc.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rocky-valley-properties.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400italic|Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/dmxResponsiveText.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptLibrary/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptLibrary/dmxResponsiveText.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptLibrary/dmxDataBindings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptLibrary/dmxDataSet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* dmxDataSet name "rvHdsPropAllFeatured" */
       jQuery.dmxDataSet(
         {"id": "rvHdsPropAllFeatured", "url": "dmxDatabaseSources/rvDsPropAllFeatured.php", "data": {"limit": "25"}, "dataSourceType": "database", "dataType": "jsonp"}
       );
  /* END dmxDataSet name "rvHdsPropAllFeatured" */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptLibrary/dmxDataFilters.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  $today = date("Y-m-d");
  $todayAnnual = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 years'));
?>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="/property-images/stellenbosch-backdrop-for-rocky-valley.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="row rv-dark-green-bg">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 text-center">
      <div class="dmxResponsiveText" id="rv-company-slogan">
        <h1 class="rv-heading-font rv-heading-colour noMarg pad-rv-company-slogan">In the Country, you will live for the first time ever !</h1>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
       jQuery(document).ready(
         function()
           {
             jQuery("#rv-company-slogan").dmxResponsiveText(
               {}
             );
           }
       );
        // ]]>
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      Featured property for you !
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-pull-1" data-binding-repeat="{{rvHdsPropAllFeatured.data}}" data-binding-id="repeatRvHdsPropAllFeatured">FEATURED {{prop_type.default( "property" ).uppercase( )}} {{prop_deal_type.replace( "buy", "for sale" ).uppercase( )}} Web Ref No: {{prop_ref_no}} {{prop_price.currency( "R", ".", ",", 2 )}}{{prop_bed_no}} Bedrooms: 
        Bathrooms: {{prop_bath_no}}
        Garages: {{prop_garage_no}}        
        <?php
          $rvGetPropId = '{{prop_id}}';
          $rvDirSearch = 'property-images/'.$rvGetPropId.'/';
          $rvFeaturedImageFinder = glob($rvDirSearch."MainPSW-*.jpg");
          foreach($rvFeaturedImageFinder as $image) {
              echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="img-responsive" /><br />';
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a real difference (alteration) between your two code snippets. What do you mean exactly with `// Returns the 10 ....`? Is it an array? If you `echo` the parameter of `glob()` in your top snippet, does it look correct?

Comment: the difference between the 2 code snippets is that in the first I am dynamically getting the folder name I want to look through, the second I am manually entering just a single folder for it to look through, the second example works but wont go through all the folders. The 10 I refer to are the 10 results from a mysql query.

Comment: Right. Can you show us the actual code (with the loop)?

Comment: I edited the post with the full code but dont know if it is going to make much sense because my repeat region is made with DMXzone Database Connecter/HTML5 Data Bindings etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if `{{prop_id}}` in PHP code is evaluated by DMXzone; echo the glob param and see what path it is looking at. My guess is `"property-images/{{prop_id}}/MainPSW-*.jpg"`.

Comment: the path that comes back is "property-images//MainPSW-*.jpg"